# Cumulative Probability Question

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm doing this question and I'm a bit confused, I was wondering if anyone would be able to shed some light on how to do it?

The question is:

Find the probability that in a box of 100 light bulbs, there will be at least 20 bulbs that have a lifespan of longer than 1000 hours. The probability of a lightbulb having a lifespan of greater than 1000 hours is 0.15.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hint: Use an approximation to a binomial distribution.

Comment: @GrahamKemp What is wrong with the binomial distribution?

Comment: @BCLC only the effort required for calculations.  (Though, I suppose that has becoming less of an issue with modern computing power.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: Use binomial distribution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function

There is an example on the page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Example

Hint 2: The probability that 20 bulbs will have a lifespan of longer than 1000 hours.

$P(X = 20) = \binom{100}{20} 0.15^{20} (1-0.15)^{100-20}$ where X is a (binomially distributed) random variable representing the # of bulbs that will have a lifespan of longer than 1000 hours.

Hint 3: The probability that 21 bulbs will have a lifespan of longer than 1000 hours.

$P(X = 21) = \binom{100}{21} 0.15^{21} (1-0.15)^{100-21}$

The answer: $P(X \geq 20) = \sum_{x=20}^{100} \binom{100}{x} 0.15^{x} (1-0.15)^{100-x}$

or

$P(X \geq 20) = 1 - P(X \leq 19) = 1 - P(X < 20) = 1 - \sum_{x=1}^{19} \binom{100}{x} 0.15^{x} (1-0.15)^{100-x}$

Comment: Shouldn't there be $1-$ on the first two elements of your last line?

Comment: @BrianTung No. Thanks.